# dhcp: lease expiration vs. infinite lease

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, dhclient

As per RFC2131, when the lease expires the client has to stop using the IP address. So do I understand right that if the lease lifetime is set to infinite on the server, then the client does not need to renew/rebind its IP, and thus the server does not have to provide these timeouts (option 58 and 59) to client?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on

Comment: I'm rather asking to help interpret the standard, rfc2131 in particular, how is that off-topic?

Comment: What's the actual benefit? You need to keep track of leased addresses anyway and keeping track of the lease start for each isn't really much hassle. An infinite lease time isn't practical as you lose control of the clients and eventually run out of pool addresses.

Comment: @Zac67 my goal is to statically bind dhcp clients with IP addresses, I think that having an infinite lease timeout could ensure this in a transparent way, instead of manually fixinf relation between a MAC address and IP address.